# nodejs server choose port if default not available

Tags: npm, npm-install

We want to start the nodejs server on a different port if default (3000) is not available. Is there any module which does this?

Actually we are trying to publish our application as repository & when user tries to install this; application should auto launch in the browser with the port at which it is listening.

This will run locally on a system; so suppose user is using 3000; then application should check for 3001 or so on...

Answer (score 1):

This is the way to do it

```
 app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
 app.listen()
```

Comment: thanks for reply but my requirement is little diff...I have updated my question

Comment: Thats how you listen to a port. I dont think there is any supported module for that.